# Disable all dates before the currentDate in DateField

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

How to create a DateField in flex, that would disable all the dates before today's current date.

```
<mx:DateField id="dateField2" yearNavigationEnabled="true" 
                disabledRanges="{[ {rangeEnd: new Date(dateBeforeCurrentDate} ]}" color="0x000000"/>
```

I understand I will have to do sometime like the code above. But I don't know how to get dateBeforeCurrentDate, so that all the date from yesterday will be disabled.

Please let me know.

Regards
Zee

Answer (score 3):

I think you're stuck with millisecond arithmetic.  That's what's used in [Adobe's docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=08_Dates_and_times_3.html):

```
function getYesterday():Date {
    var today:Date = new Date();
    var millisecondsPerDay:Number = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24;

    var yesterday:Date = new Date();
    yesterday.setTime(today.getTime() - millisecondsPerDay);
}
```

You could probably pull in a library to do this (see, e.g. [Flex Date Utils](http://code.google.com/p/flexdateutils/)) if you're going to be doing any more date arithmetic.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you need this:

```
<mx:DateField disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date()}]}"/>
```

Current date is just "new Date()".

Comment: no .. actually I am looking for a day before currentDate. I am sorry for not being clear in my question.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this works:

```
disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date((new Date()).getTime() - (1000*60*60*24))}]}"
selectableRange="{{rangeStart : new Date()}}"
```

You could probably extract the range into a bindable object.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should solve the problem:

```
<mx:DateField disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date(null, null, new Date().date - 1)}]}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why use any thing more complex than:

```
<mx:DateField disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date()}]}"/>
<mx:DateField selectableRange="{{rangeStart : new Date()}}" y="50"/>
```

[www.nucleusplus.com](http://www.nucleusplus.com)

Answer (score 0):

```
disabledRanges="{[{rangeEnd: new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth(),new Date().getDate()-1)}]}"
```

This works for Me :)